# Getting slow query with high schemaLock time

Tags: mongodb, go, database-design, schema

I am working on a project, in which I have used mongoDb as database.
I am working on the cron, in which there was high mongoDb input/output operations, i.e. there was around 10k/s i/o operations on mongoDb including get, insert and update queries.
My system specifications are:-
RAM:- 384GB
OS:- ubunutu 22.04
MongoDb version:- 4.4
MongoDb storage engine:- WiredTiger

During my entire cron, there was no change into the schema of the database, there was only get and update queries are running. In which around 95% of the queries are Get query.

My problem is that, mongoDb becomes slow after a certain period of time, to find out the problem, I start analysing slow query logs, and I have found that there was high time of schemaLock into the db queries.

> {"t":{"$date":"2023-04-05T12:23:26.702+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":51803,   "ctx":"conn4409","msg":"Slow query","attr":{"type":"command","ns":"canadaloctest1867_bk_db.users","command":{"find":"users","filter":{"_id":1,"status":{"$exists":true,"$ne":9}},"limit":1,"projection":{"status":1},"singleBatch":true,"lsid":{"id":{"$uuid":"c00762d0-98b6-41ab-adac-163039f60c0f"}},"$db":"canadaloctest1867_bk_db"},"planSummary":"IXSCAN { _id: 1 }","keysExamined":1,"docsExamined":1,"cursorExhausted":true,"numYields":1,"nreturned":1,"queryHash":"D7A7C611","planCacheKey":"1FD4C0F8","reslen":147,"locks":{"FeatureCompatibilityVersion":{"acquireCount":{"r":2}},"ReplicationStateTransition":{"acquireCount":{"w":2}},"Global":{"acquireCount":{"r":2}},"Database":{"acquireCount":{"r":2}},"Collection":{"acquireCount":{"r":2}},"Mutex":{"acquireCount":{"r":1}}},"storage":{"data":{"bytesRead":133345,"timeReadingMicros":126},"timeWaitingMicros":{"handleLock":120764,"schemaLock":8429126}},"protocol":"op_msg","durationMillis":8654}}

According to the [mongoDb documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/database-profiler/#mongodb-data-system.profile.storage.timeWaitingMicros.schemaLock), schemaLock will happen if we are modifying the schema.
I have two questions:-

- Why this schemaLock happens, if there was no change into the schema in the entire transaction?
- What can be the possible solution to prevent this situation?

Answer (score 0):

schemaLock is a lock that MongoDB acquires when it needs to modify the schema of a collection, such as creating or dropping an index. However, schemaLock can also be acquired by some read operations that need to access the collection metadata, such as explain or listIndexes. This can cause contention with other operations that need the same lock.

Some possible solutions to prevent this situation are:

- Reduce the frequency of schema modifications, such as creating or dropping indexes, especially on large collections.
- Avoid running explain or listIndexes on collections that are frequently accessed by other operations.
- Use WiredTiger as the storage engine, which has a more granular locking mechanism than MMAPv1.
- Upgrade to MongoDB 4.2 or later, which has improved the performance of schemaLock by reducing its scope and duration.
- Monitor and optimize your queries using tools such as the profiler, the Performance Advisor, or db.currentOp. You can also use indexes, projections, and query hints to improve query efficiency.

Comment: Hello @xakepp35, thanks for reply, I am not modifying the schema in any of my db query or during the entire transaction, and i have not used listIndexes command or any similar command, I have used wiredtiger as the storage engine. my mongoDb version is 4.4, and all the db queries are fully optimized, but i am facing this issue regularly.

Answer (score 0):

You may be hitting to the WiredTiger checkpointing performance issue which is also raised in [WT-5479 Checkpoint schema lock can cause long stalls in command execution on systems with many active data handles](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/WT-5479)

To summarise, MongoDB relies on WiredTiger's [checkpointing](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/upcoming/core/wiredtiger/#snapshots-and-checkpoints) mechanism to write in-memory data to disk in a consistent way to provide data durability. Checkpointing is a task that occurs periodically in the background. In the starting phase of the WiredTiger checkpoints, a schema lock is taken to prevent the handle list from being modified. Handle list consists of databases, collections, indexes available at the point of checkpoint. Sometimes starting phase takes longer which in turn causes schema lock to be hold longer. DDL tasks stall until the lock gets released.

There are enhancements in the later versions of the MongoDB which improves the performance of checkpointing task. Though can't say it's completely resolved as I can still observe long schema locks on 5.0 under load.

Besides upgrade, if you have large number of data handles (i.e databases, collections, indexes), you can review your schema to reduce the size of handle list. It will help ease the pressure on checkpointing as it needs to iterate over that list which also increases the overall duration of schema lock.